# Simple keyword search with full match

Tags: php

I need simple keyword search.

I have objects that have associated set of keywords with them. I need way to reliable search for these keywords.

After search for some set of keywords search library should return ids of objects associated with these keywords. Additional i need to know is there a full match(all searched keywords are presented in single set [associated with object]).

I want to avoid building query with multiple OR operators.

Can you point me to some library or tutorial how I can achieve this?

Comment: Mysql table of myisam type, full text indexes on your fields and use MATCH()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see only a php tag i assume no DB is involved. but it is a list of objects as you state.

I don't quite know what you mean by building query when there would not be a DB, but question is a bit unclear.

I assume this is the class for the objects you are talking about:

```
class SomeObject
{

    private $id;
    private $keywords = array();

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
  public function getKeywords()
    {
        return $this->keywords;
    }

}
```

Then this would be the solution:

```
function filterObjectArray($objectArray, $search)
{
    $resultIds = array();
    $resultObjects = array();
    foreach ($objectArray as $object)
    {
        foreach ($object->getKeywords() as $keyword)
        {
            if ($search == $keyword)
            {
                $resultIds[] = $object->getId();
                $resultObjects[] = $object;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $resultObjects;
    // or you could do return $resultIds; But i think returning the objects is a nicer solution.
}
```

Now lets assume it is DB related with folowing tables:

```
someobject
 \ id
 \ name 
 \ etc

keywords
 \ id
 \ keyword
 \ someobjectid
```

then it would simply be:

```
    select 
id 
from someobject o 
where 
exists (select 1 from keywords k where k.keyword = 'thekeywordiamlookingfor' and k.objectid = someobject.id)
```